# GWT ComboBox isn't working after SmartGwt Integration

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smart Gwt components are not rendered in html div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024423/smart-gwt-components-are-not-rendered-in-html-div-tag)

My problem is that I had a project which was running gwt widgets nicely. Now for some client requirements, we introduced some smartGwt changes in it.

The problem is that all those requirements have been done successfully, but as a result or something, the previous ComboBox dropdown isn't working, none of them. Please help.

Do I have to post the code also (because its too large)? If you want it, I will try to paste it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My simple solution is - when using smartgwt, don't mix it with vanilla gwt or gxt. If you have to, all the smartgwt canvases must be parent of vanilla gwt or gxt widgets. There should be no instances where a gwt or gxt widget is a parent of a smartgwt widget. I don't have the confidence that mucking around with the z-index would work well in a complex ui.

Comment: @kunal, look at answer of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024423/smart-gwt-components-are-not-rendered-in-html-div-tag

Comment: Thanks! its working now.
@BlessedGeek, thanks! i will take care of this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you  mean by "isn't working". There are zindex issues when you use Gwt and Smartgwt side by side. You can have a look at this thread ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713770/gwt-suggestbox-with-smartgwt))if it's this sort of problem. If not give us more details.

Comment: yes, the same problem. Thanks for the reply. I can't use the ComboBoxItem of smartgwt (for that i have to change whole system of codes).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to increase the z-index of gwt part. I searched for that but didn't understand much about. Please help, it would be very nice of you.

Comment: You have to look at your page with Firebug and find the css class name of the element you want to increase the z-index. When you know the class you go in your css file and had the z-index override:

Comment: For example .gwt-SuggestBoxPopup { 
 z-index: 1000000;
} As your Smartgwt will have their z-index attribute high but lower than that your widget will always appear on top of them.

Comment: thanks! its working now. Actually i was giving the z-index from some css file. it was not taking those values even if i give setstylename() method also.
 
 Then i checked from where its taking values (with the help of firefox tool). i changed in the exact file (ext-all.js). Now its working fine.
 thanks for your help.